# Wildcard between double quotes - Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, search, replace

I am working on this now for a few hours and even after searching the internet I couldn't figure it out.
I wrote a Batch file with following code:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "search=return ".*" "
set "replace=return "%DATE%""

set "textFile=C:\PathToFile"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
 set "line=%%i"
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
 >>"%textFile%" echo(!line!
 endlocal
)
```

My Problem is that in the "search" part I need a sort of wildcard between the double quotes. I tried regex, I tried *, ? and escaping the quotes but nothing works! Also the code above doesn't work. I bet it's a very simple mistake but I can't figure it out.

I'm looking for something like this in the file:`return "6.20.99.99"`

And the result should be: `return "16.09.2015"`

**EDIT**
In case someone has the same problem - I posted the solution in a comment but here is it again:

`jrepl "return \q.*\q" "return \q%date%\q" /X /F "C:\PathToFile" /o -`

Comment: What is `break` you stated in the set of `for` (the part after `in`)? there is no command like that, so is it a third-party tool you're using?

Comment: If you are trying to search and replace in a variable, just focus on it and remove useless code here. Make the code simple.

Comment: @aschipfl  `break` is an internal command and will just create a zero byte file in the way it is being misused.

Comment: I was not aware of that, @foxidrive; since which Windows version is it available?

Comment: @aschipfl It goes back as far as MSDOS and is seldom used.  Making zero byte files is a new job for it. :)

Comment: Thanks, @foxidrive; I never stop learning... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you've described and puts in todays date:
input.txt and output.txt are the files being used.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "day=%dt:~6,2%.%dt:~4,2%.%dt:~0,4%"
call jrepl "return \q.*\q" "return \q%day%\q" /x /f "input.txt" /o "output.txt"
```

This uses a native Windows batch script called `Jrepl.bat` (by dbenham)
jrepl.bat can be downloaded from: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4otci4d4s8x5ni4/Jrepl.bat
and it can also be found here: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044

Place it in the same folder as the batch file, or in a folder that is on the system path.

Comment: I actually tried to avoid the usage of third party software. But if nothing works I'll come back to this. Thanks!

Comment: @StefanieWeber  I can understand, though Dave Benham's batch file uses no third party software (and is also hosted on Stackoverflow), and the wmic executable is also built into modern Windows.

Comment: I tried it and this is what I've got now. It's a bit shorter:
`jrepl "return \q.*\q" "return \q%date%\q" /X /F "C:\PathToFile" /o -`

And it works! I'm so happy!

Comment: @StefanieWeber Cool.  :)  Just commenting that the `%date%` variable changes by region and by user settings, so it's not reliable when used on other machines.  If it works in your situation that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
set "search=return ^".*^" "
echo %search%
```

which will return

`return ".*"`

<s>Update: Also substring does not work with wildcard.
http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html</s>

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried that and it still doesn't work. I'm not using any third party software so I think the .* is wrong here in my code. It can't find anything in between the double quotes and therefore it doesn't change the value to a date